# jQuery JSON append ul according to the number of array sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want jQuery to make new `ul` for each set of products.
Inside of each `ul`, all items of each set will be appended.
The result was unexpected; there should be only 2 `ul`, but
11 `ul` were appended.

My jQuery

```
$.getJSON('/products.json', function (result) {
    var booksobj = result.ebooks.basic;

    /* EBOOKS*/
    $.each(booksobj.set, function(i, item) {
        $('#ebook').append('<ul>'); // Append new list sets
        $('#ebook ul').append('<li><a href="#" data-id="' + item.product_id + '" data-type="' + item.type + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>');
    });
});
```

products.json

```
{
    "ebooks": {
        "basic": {
            "set": [
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample",
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "type": "ebook"
                },
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample",
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "type": "ebook"
                }, // ...
            ],
            "set": [
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample",
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "type": "ebook"
                },
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample",
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "type": "ebook"
                }, // ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping over `set` and for each item inside a set, you're creating a new `ul` element. You need to have multiple loops where you create an `ul` and afterwards add all the `li`s for the section. I changed your data structure, you don't need the `set` properties (and they're overriding each other as property names are unique). `basic` is now an array which consists of arrays which represent a `set`.

```js
var data = {
    "ebooks": {
        "basic": [
            [
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample 1",
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "type": "ebook"
                },
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample 2",
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "type": "ebook"
                },
            ],
            [
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample 3",
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "type": "ebook"
                },
                {
                    "title": "PDF Sample 4",
                    "product_id": 2,
                    "type": "ebook"
                },
            ]
        ]
    }
}


data.ebooks.basic.forEach(function(set) {
    var $list = $('<ul></ul>');
  
    set.forEach(function(pdf) {
        $list.append('<li>' + pdf.title +  '</li>')
    });
              
    $('#ebook').append($list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ebook"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem stems from the selectors in this snippet:

```
  $('#ebook').append('<ul>'); // Append new list sets
  $('#ebook ul').append('<li><a href="#" data-id="' + item.product_id + '" data-type="' + item.type + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>');
```

The selector "$('#ebook ul')" won't select the newly added ul in the iteration, instead it'll append to the first match (so the first ul added to the #ebook div). Instead, try chaining your calls like so:

```
/* EBOOKS*/
$.each(booksobj.set, function(i, item) {
     $('#ebook').append('<ul>').append('<li><a href="#" data-id="' + item.product_id + '" data-type="' + item.type + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>');
});
```

Working example with JSON data in a variable: http://codepen.io/JasonGraham/pen/WxbvRo

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is use $('#ebook ul'), another question, why you use the key "set" two times? No make sense,

```
var data = {
"ebooks": {
    "basic": [
        [
            {
                "title": "PDF Sample 1",
                "product_id": 1,
                "type": "ebook"
            },
            {
                "title": "PDF Sample 2",
                "product_id": 2,
                "type": "ebook"
            },
        ],
        [
            {
                "title": "PDF Sample 3",
                "product_id": 1,
                "type": "ebook"
            },
            {
                "title": "PDF Sample 4",
                "product_id": 2,
                "type": "ebook"
            },
        ]
    ]
}
}


$.each(data.ebooks.basic, function(i, item) {
    $('#ebook').append('<ul>'); // Append new list sets
    $.each(item, function(i, item2) {
    $('#ebook ul:last').append('<li><a href="#" data-id="' + item2.product_id + '" data-type="' + item2.type + '">' + item2.title + '</a></li>');
});
});
```

see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efo0ug73/1/)

Comment: your making `ul` for each item of each set

Comment: oh, sorry, not more, now, have 2 arrays, the first loop, create the ul, the second, create the li inside of the last ul element